# How to correctly deallocate a list of pointer to pair?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, memory-leaks

In my c++ program I have this variable:

```
std::list<std::pair<MyClass,MyClass>*>* myList = 
    new std::list<std::pair<MyClass,MyClass> * >()
```

How can I correctly delete all information of this structure to avoid memory leaks? I think to do in this mode:

```
list<pair<MyClass,MyClass>*>::iterator it;
for(it = myList->begin(); it != myList->end(); it++){
    delete *it;
}
delete myList;
```

Is it a correct approach?

Comment: My first advice would be to *not* use so many pointers to begin with. No pointers, no `new` or `new[]`, and no need to `delete` or `delete[]`. And unless you have very specific requirements use `std::vector` instead of a `std:list`.

Comment: If you're used to Java, you need to unlearn the habit of typing `new` to create objects. The common C++ approach would be to use `std::vector<std::pair<MyClass, MyClass>> myList;` and not worry about it.

Comment: if the list owns the objects it should contain the objects not pointers, if it doesnt own then then it shouldnt bother to delete them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is correct, it will delete everything.

However, I would recommend you do not create your *list* dynamically because it already stores its internal data dynamically. Then, use `std::unique_ptr` to do your deleting automatically.

Instead of:

```
std::list<std::pair<MyClass,MyClass> * > * myList=new std::list<std::pair<MyClass,MyClass> * >();
```

This:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<std::pair<MyClass, MyClass>>> myList;
```

Now, when you remove and element from your *list* the `std::unique_ptr` will delete it for you.

However **in your specific example** there is really no need to store your elements as pointers to begin with, since this is an **owning** container (responsible for deleting its contents).

So you can just do this:

```
std::list<std::pair<MyClass, MyClass>> myList;
```

And forget about pointers altogether.

Comment: Of what benefit is it to have nodes containing pointers, instead of just nodes? `std::list` is guaranteed to have stable elements already

Comment: @Galik Yes, you are right, I could use std::list<std::pair<MyClass, MyClass>> myList; , I'm using it only for do some test with pointer.
But my "mode" to deallocate is it logically correct?

Comment: @Antonio1996 But I would stress that it is no longer considered good practice to use raw pointers with `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you will also need to delete the first ( "Stato" ) element of every pair, using a call like

```
delete (*it).first;
```

Answer (score 0):

This data structure is a bit of a nightmare:

```
std::list<std::pair<MyClass,MyClass> * > *
```

This is a pointer to a list (which is the pointer to a head and tail node), where the nodes in the list are pointers.  So to access the first element, you have to dereference three pointers.  That's not good for speed, nor memory usage.

Simplify:

```
std::list<std::pair<MyClass,MyClass> >
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm using it only for do some test with pointer.
But my "mode" to deallocate is it logically correct?